# Is the electromagnetic field an Abelian gauge field?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-theory

I was reading an article on chiral symmetry breaking in QCD, and the motivation to my question lies in the fact that I've stuck onto one sentence, because I could not reason why it was true.

The electromagnetic field is a gauge field that carries $U(1)$ symmetry, and, for that, I think it's reasonable that the answer should be "yes", since $U(1)$ transformations are commutative. However, I can't seem to prove that EM field is $U(1)$ invariant.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! What are your thoughts? Please note that you are expected to have thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question. And it's important to detail where you're stuck and why, in order to attract good answers. You can consider checking the [advice on writing good questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @stafusa The thing is... I've searched before (on books and other questions here), but I'm just not certain if my conclusion is right. I thought the question was simple as it is, so I didn't add anything more to that. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No inconvenience and no need to apologize. It's important to explain where your question comes from: why do you think it's Abelian and why you think it might actually not be. This way the question becomes more interesting and clearer, increasing its changes of attracting high quality answers.

Comment: I see... Thanks for your patience, @stafusa. I'll edit the description to my question.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, I didn't downvote your question, but the downvoter probably found it too 'skinny'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"However, I can't seem to prove that EM field is U(1) invariant."

That's because the gauge field doesn't transform the same way as the particle that has the symmetry it couples to. To see how gauge theories work with field theories (not even, necessarily, quantum ones) with these sorts of groups, you really have to look in to [the mathematics behind them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory#An_example:_Electrodynamics) (see also: [quantum electrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics#Mathematics)).

The short version is that there is some other field that is invariant under local $\mathrm{U}(1)$ transformation, and having a gauge field that undergoes gauge transformations is necessary to construct a Lagrangian that has derivatives of that field and is invariant under the local, "gauged", $\mathrm{U}(1)$ transformation.

I would type more here, but I'd basically be copying what's in the Wikipedia links provided or any introductory quantum field theory textbook.